# Can an enum return description (string) in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm struggling with my GraphQL API because I need to take advantage of Enums while keeping their full description in the frontend.

In short:
I have different states for a product: `"Has been sent"`, `"Not sent yet"`, `"Received"`.
So this is the right place to use Enums:

```
enum ProductState {
  HAS_BEEN_SENT
  NOT_SENT_YET
  RECEIVED
}
```

But I need to display the **proper strings** on the frontend ("`Has been sent`", and not "`HAS_BEEN_SENT`").

I can't use a simple solution as "replace underscores with spaces and lowercase the string" because my API is not in English but in French (so I have accents and special characters).

**Can't an Enum return a string? Or an object?**
I tried with directives but impossible to get it work...

Actually I don't care how it is written in the database (the uppercase or lowercase form) nor in the GraphQL API. I just need my client to access to the different product states in their "French" form.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know there is only one supported syntax for defining enums in GRAPHQL, which is the one you are using. **You cannot associate an enum with a string value.**

```
#NOTE: I would probably use a more descriptive name as opposed to ProductState
enum AllowedProductStatus { 
  HAS_BEEN_SENT
  NOT_SENT_YET
  RECEIVED
}
```

However, if you use apollo server you can use resolvers to add custom values.

```
const resolvers = {
  AllowedProductStatus: {
    HAS_BEEN_SENT: "Has been sent", 
    NOT_SENT_YET: "Not sent yet", 
    RECEIVED: "Received"
  }
};
```

Alternatively, If you simply wants to make it unique you could also use the directive @unique

```
type Product {
  status: String! @unique
}
```

Hope it was helpful.